# Appending to a list inside an object also appends to that list in other objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help, not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've initiated `numbers` as an instance variable, not a class variable. Somehow, when appending to `x`'s numbers, it also gets appended to `y`'s numbers. Instance variables should be independent of one another, no?

### Code

```
class Foo:
        def __init__(self, numbers=[]):
                self.numbers = numbers

x = Foo()
y = Foo()

x.numbers.append(3)

print("X NUMBERS")
print(x.numbers)

print("Y NUMBERS")
print(y.numbers)
```

### Output

```
X NUMBERS
[3]
Y NUMBERS
[3]
```

N.b - this problem only arises when a default parameter is provided for `numbers` in the constructor.

Comment: TL;DR: Don't use mutable default arguments, or at least don't mutate mutable default arguments unless you want this behavior (although there are likely better way of creating "static" data).

Comment: Incredible, thank you